# PHPExcel: Can't style merged cells

Tags: php, phpexcel, dompdf

I can't figure out how to set font styles for merged cells. Either by opening an XLS file with merged cells, or creating a doc from scratch with PHPExcel, merged cells won't style, they insist in being too TimesNewRomany for my needs.

Here's an abbreviated version of my code:

```
$excel = new PHPExcel();
$excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

# I know beforehand my spreadsheet spans from A1 to G42,
# so I set styles for all those cells:
$excel
  ->getActiveSheet()
  ->getStyle('A1:G42')
  ->getFont()
  ->setName('Helvetica')
  ->setSize(8);

# Now, onto some merging:
$sheet = $excel->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->mergeCells('D2:G2');
```

Then I go on and ouput it all as PDF using DomPDF. All my cells look nice and tidy wearing Helvetica@8px, except the merged ones. Not even targeting them specifically:

```
$sheet->getStyle('D2:G2')->getFont()->setName('Helvetica')->setSize(8);
```

What I've tried so far, from Google results:

- Using `applyFromArray()` on cells
- Setting styles **after** merging cells
- Using `getActiveSheet()->getDefaultStyle()->applyFromArray()`

Any additional ideas?

Comment: What does the output HTML+CSS for the merged cells look like? Perhaps the styling for those cells is not output correctly. Or maybe dompdf is interpreting it incorrectly. Either way, seeing the HTML could help figure out the issue.

Comment: @BrianS I'll check it out for sure! For now, I've upgraded the scripts to the latest version from the Github repo, and it works a helluva lot better. Handles merged cells just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the **only** way to solve this issue, but apparently I was using an outdated versión of PHPExcel, wich presumably had trouble handling merged cells.

I've just **updated the library to the latest source from Github** and problems went away. So, I have to assume it just wasn't supported in the old versions.

Comment: Could you please specify version numbers which work and doesn't work?